# Search string in string C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, split

I have a string `“EMP1$0,EMP2$1,EMP3 $1, Emp4$ 0, emp44$1”`; these are employee codes separated by coma (`,`). Each employee code is appended with their statuses (i.e. 1 for active and 0 for inactive and separated with $ sign). Employee code will not contain spaces, but space can be possible between employee code and $. I need to check if an employee code say “EMP4” is present in this string. Which will be best approach?

Any help is highly appreciable.

Edit:

```
var strResult = from string str in hdnEmpCodes.Value.Split(',') 
                where str.Length > 0 && str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf("$")).Trim() == lnkEmpCode.Text.Trim() 
                select str.ToString();
```

But it is not giving the desired output.

Comment: `var strResult = from string str in hdnEmpCodes.Value.Split(',')
                                                where str.Length > 0 && str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf("$")).Trim() == lnkEmpCode.Text.Trim()
                                                select str.ToString();` But it is not giving the desired output.

Comment: check the answers provided below, because God is my witness that i have no ideea why you are using a linq query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start with the following:

```
var text = "EMP1$0,EMP2$1,EMP3 $1, Emp4$ 0, emp44$1";
```

Then you can perform this query to extract the "EMP" codes:

```
var query =
    from x in text.Split(',').Select(_ => _.Trim())
    let y = x.Split('$').Select(_ => _.Trim())
    where y.Any()
    select y.First();
```

This would give the following result:

[image: EMP query result]

It would now be a simple matter of checking if any of the returned values match.

```
var found = query.Any(x => x.ToUpperInvariant() == "EMP4");
```

Does this do what you need?

Answer (score 3):

you can use the string.Contains method

```
bool employeeExistsInString = string.Contains(yourString);
```

However would have been nice if you would have at least googled it first.

Comment: If the employee codes are EMP44 and EMP40 in the string and i am going to search for EMP4... will this give correct output?

Comment: yes, if you are looking for EMP44 it will return true only if its EMP44 exactly.

Comment: @Freeman - techdo's comment is valid - your code will trigger a false positive if you search for "EMP4" and you have employees with the codes "EMP44" & "EMP40".

Answer (score 2):

Use string.Contains

```
if(str.Contains("EMP4"))
```

EDIT: based on your comment.

Since you said in your question that your values will be comma separated. You may try the following.

```
string str = "EMP10, EMP44, EMP5"; //your sample string. 
string[] tempArray = str.Split(',');
if (tempArray.Contains("EMP4")) //This will result in Not Found
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found");
}
if (str.Contains("EMP4")) //But a simple string.Contains will result in matching 
                          //it to EMP44
{
    Console.WriteLine("here");
}
```

Comment: @techdo, you may have that in your question. Because I missed it, and seems like others as well.

Comment: String is `“EMP1$0,EMP2$1,EMP3 $1, Emp4$ 0, emp44$1”`, i.e. in `EMP1$0`, `EMP1` is employee code and 0 is the status.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of the csv and use contains on the list

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex

```
Regex r = new Regex("EMP4[^\\d]"); 
Match m = r.Match(yourString); 
if (m.Success) 
{
    // your code
}
```

This searches any EMP4 string not followed by another digit